# Is the purpose of Dependency Injection pattern lost when you cast the parent interface to its child in C#?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a Data Repository interface called `IRepository`. `BakerRepository` inherits the generic CRUD methods from it. Now for `BakerRepository`, it may have some methods that are special to itself. For example, a method called `Bake`.

I am using Unity.Mvc for the container of the dependencies. This was how I originally use it in the controller, which I learned from a tutorial that I read a few days ago:

```
private IRepository<Baker, int> _repository;

public BakersController(IRepository<Baker, int> repo)
{
    _repository = repo;
}
```

The container will basically give me the `BakerRepository` implementation. However, when I try to use the `Bake` method, which is unique to `BakerRepository`, it returns an error because `_repository` is of type `IRepository<Baker, int>`, and thus knows no `Bake` method.

So I tried this implementation instead:

```
private BakerRepository _repository;

public BakersController(IRepository<Baker, int> repo)
{
    _repository = repo as BakerRepository;
}
```

I don't fully understand the DI pattern, I'm only using it now because I learned it as a part of a tutorial about data repositories in ASP.Net MVC. I read up about it and I thought it's actually a good design pattern so I decided to keep using it, although I don't get it a hundred percent.

Now I'm wondering if I rendered the purpose dependency injections useless if I do the implementation this way. I don't understand DI pattern enough, and I just couldn't find an exact answer elsewhere.

Comment: To execute your Bake method with `IRepository` you could use Reflection or define a property of type `Action` in your `IRepository`. With reflection you can call your method if it exists and the `Action` can be executed directly. But why do you pass `IRepository` if you know you need to call Bake method?

Comment: This specific problem has nothing to do with DI but rather with abstractions in general. You're using interfaces (abstraction) in order not to tie yourself with a specific implementation (typically, for easier unit testing and "swapability"). To me it sounds more like you want the `Bake()` method to be part of `Baker` and not `IRepository` (which should only bother itself with persistence and not logic).

Comment: I would say that you don’t lose the positive aspects of DI. The DI pattern is just a methods to invert the control of implementation aspects from inside a class to outside (which you also do) to facilitate the possibly to change implementation without knowing the implementation of the class where you inject an object. The possibility for injection automation is an additional positive aspect to provide a better resource allocation.

- Sorry was a bit slow in typing ;-)

Comment: @haim770 Hi. So what do you think I should do instead?

Comment: @prinzechristian, *Technically* you can write an extension-method that may solve this artificial problem. But, you really need to ask yourself whether `Bake()` really belongs to a repository at all, and if it does, can it be added to the interface? The answer is probably no, especially when you're using a *generic* repository. Again, I don't think `Bake()` has nothing to do with repository at all, what does it intends to do?

Comment: @haim770 That's just an example, actually, to point that some methods maybe unique to specific repositories. What I actually have is a HasName method which checks if a Name is already in use in the database, which not all entities will need to implement. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @prinzechristian, In case `HasName()` is only applicable to `IRepository<Baker, int>`, I guess extension-method is your best bet. Something like: `public static bool HasName(this IRepository<Baker, int> rep) { ... }`. Otherwise, a non-generic repository is the way to go (`IBakerRepository`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting the `IRepository<Baker, int>` in the constructor to `BakerRepository` violates at least two out of 5 [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles:

- [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) is violated, because this will cause changes to a different part of the system (the replacement or decoration of the repository for instance) to cause sweeping changes throughout the system, since you might be using the `BakerRepository` in many places.
- [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) is likely violated, because it is unlikely that your `BakersController` uses all `BakerRepository` method.
- [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) is violated, because your `BakersController` depends directly on a concrete type, instead of an abstraction. This makes it harder to change and evolve implementations independently.

None of these problems can be solved by changing the the `IRepository<Baker, int>` parameter to `BakersRepository`. Instead, you should break out this special `Bake` method and place it behind its own abstraction, for instance:

```
public interface IBakeHandler
{
    BakeResults Bake([parameters]);
}
```

You can mark the `BakeRepository` with this new `IBakeHandler` interface as well:

```
class BakeRepository : IRepository<Bake>, IBakeHandler
{
}
```

This allows you to let the `BakeController` to depend on `IBakeHandler` instead:

```
private IBakeHandler _bakeHandler;

public BakersController(IBakeHandler bakeHandler)
{
    _bakeHandler = bakeHandler;
}
```

This prevents violating of the SOLID principles, because:

- The replacement of the implementation with a proxy, decorator or adapter will not ripple through the system; the `BakerController` is unaffected by such change.
- The `IRepository<T>` and especially the `IBakeHandler` stay narrow, making it much easier to create decorators to apply cross-cutting concerns or to create mock/stub/fake implementations for testing.
- Repository and IBakeHandler implementations can be placed in assemblies that are unreferenced by the assembly that holds the controller.

Do note though that every time you break open such repository implementation to add new features you are effectively violating the Open/Closed principle and probably the Single Responsibility Principle as well.

In case you have many of those 'extra' repository features, you will start to see many one-method interfaces like `IBakeHandler`. Once you see this happening, extract new generic abstractions out of these interfaces. You can apply well-known patterns such as described [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I just have follow up questions. Do you mean that `BakerRepository` should be inheriting from `IBakeHandler` instead of `IRepository`? What about the implementation of `IRepository` for the `BakerRepository`?

Comment: @prinzechristian I'm  saying that BakerRepository can implement both IRelository and IBakeHandler. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is to actually pass the BakerRepository to your BakerController, because that's what it depends on.

Dependency injection is, as you say, a very useful pattern. However, it is just a tool to help build your objects when you've properly extracted the dependencies of your classes. In a non framework setting you'd be responsible for building these objects, and you'd quickly tire of passing in loads of parameters. DI helps you with that. But it is optional. So, if you did it by hand, you'd always construct the BakerController with a BakerRepository passed in. Therefore the same logic would apply when you're using DI.

Comment: I'd agree with the first part, but you seem to be confusing DI with an IoC container in your second paragraph. You don't need a container to do DI.

Answer (score 0):

In direct answer to your question.  You could upcast your dependency but that would have no bearing on what D\I does for you.

Breaking out your dependencies CAN be useful for TDD also, isolating your external dependencies allows for unit testing of a class without exercising relatively expensive I\0 calls or disruptive calls.

Also breaking out dependencies allows you to focus the responsibilities of an object and having object doing one thing well.

In practice I have rarely seen or used D\I (implemented off the back of an IOC container) to change concrete implementations, having only done it recently for feature toggling

Another point is that objects which are not external I\0 could feasibly be newed up and still tested either sociably or in a solitary manner.

You shouldn't necessarily D\I everything....